# How do I add commas to numeric strings in an Anylogic presentation text object?

Tags: anylogic

I have a text object in the Anylogic presentation with the following code:
`"Infrastructure costs: £" + Math.round(flowOpRoomsPCN) + "/day"`

This text displays: *Infrastructure costs: £123456789/day*

I would like this to display: *Infrastructure costs: £123,456,789/day*

Seems a simple question but could not find the answer anywhere just yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the great Java string formatter:

```java
double value = 123_456_789.00d;
String output = String.format("Infrastructure costs: £%(,.2f/day", value);
```

The above formatting directive `%(,.2f` instructs string formatter to take in `value` and represent it as a ###,###.## pattern for positive numbers and (###,###.00) for negative.

More information is available in Java API documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: Thanks Artem, this worked well and it's straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard Java formating

`DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");`

```
"Infrastructure costs: £" + formatter.format(Math.round(flowOpRoomsPCN)) + "/day";
```

Comment: Thanks Jaco-Ben, I accepted the other answer as it seems more straightforward to me. But I guess your solution could be just as valid.

Comment: No worries, thank you.